# Validation of a mathematical formula based on user input

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, math

I know that SO is not a code generator, but I break my head and I'll got mad with this RegExp. 
I've `<input />` type text, in a HTML `<form />`. The input is automatically filled when the user double-click on elements in a specific list. 
This event will generate string like `"[text:number]"` or `"[text:number:text]"`, and place it at the cursor position in my `<input />` field.
The first goal of this process is to construct a mathematic formula structure. I mean, the generated strings between brackets will insert elements, then I want to allow the user to put **only** numbers and operators.

I've tried to bind the `keydown` event, and test the char with `String.fromCharCode(e.which);` but for the keys "+" or "-" (and other operators) this function returns alphabeticals chars. Without success.
Then, I've finally decided to use the `keyup` event, then use a RegExp to replace the `<input />` value.

```
        $("#inputID").keyup(function(){
            var formule = $(this).val();
            var valid_formule = formule.replace(CRAZY_REGEXP,'');
            $(this).val(valid_formule);
        });
```

So, my question is as follows : 
How construct a javascript RegExp, to remove all chars which **are not** between brackets, and which are differents of `()+-*/,.` and `numbers`.
An example : 
`"a[dse:1]a+a[dse:5]a+a[cat:5:sum]a+(a10a/5,5)!"`
will become
`"[dse:1]+[dse:5]-[cat:5:sum]+(10/5,5)"`

I'm open to another way to achieve my goal if you have some ideas.
Thanks !

Comment: If you want to check the well-balancing of parentheses, regexes will not do the job. You'll need a more complex parser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may try something like this:

```
var re = /[^\]\d\(\)+\-*\/,.]+(?=[^\[\]\(\)]*(?:\[|\(|$))/g;
$("#inputID").keyup(function(){
    this.value = this.value.replace(re, "");
});
```

Keep in mind, though, that you have to be sure that the parenthetical structure is coherent with your syntax.

Advice: use [RegExr](http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) to test your regular expressions, but remember that it's *more powerful* than Javascript regex support.

Comment: I can't upvote your post, but you save my day ! The next step is, like you said, to valid the global structure of the formula. Thanks ! (and +1 for the link)

Comment: You're welcome. I just did a minor edit (put `\)` twice in the first `[...]` group), but it'd work anyway.